# Is ReactJS "clever" when it comes to invoking the render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The render method of this component does use any of the props supplied to the component.

Will the component re-render when the props change regardless?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { propValue } = props;
    // do something with propValue...
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>foo</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [Related](http://lucybain.com/blog/2017/react-js-when-to-rerender/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the component will re-render unless you implement `shouldComponentUpdate`. You can inherit from [`PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) which uses shallow comparison of `prop` and `state` with previous values to determine if component should update or not.

Answer (score 3):

Will `render` be called - yes. Unless you implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to return `false`.

Will the DOM be rerendered - no.

Also you might want to take a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-constant-elements/ that hoists static elements up.

> In
>
> ```
> const Hr = () => {
>   return <hr className="hr" />;
> };
> ```
>
> Out
>
> ```
> const _ref = <hr className="hr" />;
>
> const Hr = () => {
>   return _ref;
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know react will call the render method in the following scenarios

1. when your component get mounted initially
2. when state got changed using `this.setState()`
3. when your component receives new `props`
4. when `this.forceUpdate()` get called.

since you didn't implement `shouldcomponentUpdate()` the render method is going to get called